# Get Npm dependency in node javascript file

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a package.json file with certain dependencies. One of the dependencies is jquery. The system then downloads the files into the node_modules folder.

How can I get the version of a downloaded dependency from a Javascript file invoked by the node command?

I need to read the equivalent of npm view jquery version in a node JS file?

Comment: One way would be to require the package.json of the module like so: const pkg = require('./node_modules/{package}/package.json');

console.log(pkg.version);

Comment: I don't want to read the version of the package json. But I want to read a specific dependency version like what version of JQuery is installed in node_modules.

Comment: I know, that's exactly what my snippet of code does.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
console.log(require('jquery/package.json').version);
```

It will give you the version of the package in your local node_modules.

Comment: Ok super this is it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pkginfo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkginfo), it should satisfy.

Comment: This gives me undefined:

var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");
var jquery = require("jquery");

return console.log(jquery.version);